# How can I loop through multiple update statements in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to run the following UPDATE statement on my SQLite table multiple times. `UPDATE collections SET Score = Score+1 WHERE ItemID in (SELECT ItemID FROM collections WHERE UserID = 61 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1 );`

This code should add one to the score of a random item in my collection. I need a way to run this statement n times in one query. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it need a human intervention to run that update statement? like button click?

Comment: It's run every time a user performs a certain action, yes.

Comment: what specific programming language are you using with your sqlite?

Comment: Javascript, node.js

Comment: And do you know how to write a loop in JavaScript?

Comment: I know how to do loops in javascript. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it all in one query